# how to override the Jquery.ajax function?

Tags: jquery

I want to override the $.ajax function in Jquery

I want to use the existing functionality and need to add some other functionality

Example:

get the original ajax function in to OriginalAjax variable

```
 var OriginalAjax = $.ajax 

  $.ajax = function(xhr){

      if(xhr.status ==401)
       {
          // Diplay Error in dialog box;
       }
      return(OriginalAjax(xhr));
  });
```

is it possible to override the $.ajax function? if 'Yes' Please let know how to implement it?

Comment: Is there anything specific you need in additional?

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you can do that...

```
var oldAjax = $.ajax;

$.ajax = function() {
     // Do your magic.
     return oldAjax.apply($, arguments);
};
```

...or...

```
const oldAjax = $.ajax;

$.ajax = (...args) => {
     // Do your magic.
     return oldAjax(...args);
};
```

**However**, judging by your example, you should just use a global event handler such as [`ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/), where you can check the response status.

Comment: I expanded on [this answer a bit here.](https://github.com/jmb-mage/ajax-request-tracker/blob/master/jquery.ajax.tracker.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can just override default $.ajax behavior.

Remember that $.ajax is returning promise() objects, so you will need to handle callbacks attached to done() / fail() as well.

Maybe this article can help you: http://www.svlada.com/blog/override-jquery-ajax-handler/